# Pipe in C — read and write in my program

Tags: c, pipe

I would like my program to display the result like this:

```
child: 2 4 6 8 10  
parent: 3 6 9 12 15  
child 12 14 16 18 20  
parent 18 21 24 27 30
```

etc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main(int argc,char *argv[]){
int i=0,tube1[2],tube2[2],pid,tube3[2];
if(pipe(tube1)||pipe(tube2)==-1){
perror("pipe");
exit(0);
}
pid=fork();

while(i<100){

if(pid==0){
printf("fils ");

do{
i=i+2;
printf("%d ",i);
}while(i%5!=0);


write(tube1[1],&i,sizeof(int));

read(tube2[0],&i,sizeof(int));


}

else{



printf("pere ");
read(tube1[0],&i,sizeof(int));
do{

i=i+3;
printf("%d ",i);
}while(i%5!=0);


write(tube2[1],&i,sizeof(int));



}

printf("\n");








}
close(tube1[1]);
close(tube1[0]);
close(tube2[1]);
close(tube2[0]);
}
```

But I have problems in my program; I do not understand why.

Comment: This line doesn't do what you think it does: `if(pipe(tube1)||pipe(tube2)==-1){`

Comment: @slugonamission: The line is self-inconsistent, which is bad, but it does actually work since `pipe()` returns a non-zero value (`-1`) on failure and zero on success, so the first test triggers the body of the `if` statement if the first `pipe()` fails, just as the second test triggers the body if the second `pipe()` fails.

Comment: reindent your code, put proper spaces around operators to make it readable

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then **[use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)**

Answer (score 2):

When cleaned up, your code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0, tube1[2], tube2[2], pid;
    if (pipe(tube1) == -1 || pipe(tube2) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(0);
    }
    pid = fork();

    while (i < 100)
    {
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            printf("fils ");
            do
            {
                i = i + 2;
                printf("%d ", i);
            } while (i % 5 != 0);
            putchar('\n');

            write(tube1[1], &i, sizeof(int));
            read(tube2[0], &i, sizeof(int));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("pere ");
            read(tube1[0], &i, sizeof(int));
            do
            {
                i = i + 3;
                printf("%d ", i);
            } while (i % 5 != 0);
            putchar('\n');

            write(tube2[1], &i, sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    close(tube1[1]);
    close(tube1[0]);
    close(tube2[1]);
    close(tube2[0]);
}
```

One change is that the processes output a newline after writing a sequence of numbers, rather than waiting until after the read/write operations.

The loop is convoluted because you have an outer `while (i < 100)` loop, and then each process has an inner loop that increments `i`.  Then, to further complicate things, the child sends its current value of `i` to the parent, and the parent uses that in its loop, and then the parent sends its own value of `i` to the child and the child resumes its work with the new value of `i`; rinse and repeat.  The output is:

```
fils 2 4 6 8 10 
pere 13 16 19 22 25 
fils 27 29 31 33 35 
pere 38 41 44 47 50 
fils 52 54 56 58 60 
pere 63 66 69 72 75 
fils 77 79 81 83 85 
pere 88 91 94 97 100
```

You can see that the child generates values to 10; then the parent adds 3 to the value it received from the child (hence 13) and iterates; it then sends 25 to the child, which adds 2 (hence 27) and iterates; and so on.

To get the result you seek, you need to decouple the values used in synchronization from the values to control the loop.  You also face a problem because the child will try to run longer than the parent, but fortunately, it will get a SIGPIPE signal and will die when it tries to write to the pipe that that the parent has closed — or rather, it would if it had closed the ends of the pipe that it's not using.  It would also be a good idea to flush standard output after generating the newline.  Those changes lead to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0, tube1[2], tube2[2], pid;
    if (pipe(tube1) == -1 || pipe(tube2) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(tube1[0]);
        close(tube2[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        close(tube1[1]);
        close(tube2[0]);
    }

    while (i < 100)
    {
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            printf("fils ");
            do
            {
                i = i + 2;
                printf("%d ", i);
            } while (i % 5 != 0);
            putchar('\n');
            fflush(stdout);

            int j = 0;
            write(tube1[1], &j, sizeof(int));
            read(tube2[0], &j, sizeof(int));
        }
        else
        {
            int j = 0;
            read(tube1[0], &j, sizeof(int));

            printf("pere ");
            do
            {
                i = i + 3;
                printf("%d ", i);
            } while (i % 5 != 0);
            putchar('\n');
            fflush(stdout);

            write(tube2[1], &j, sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    close(tube1[1]);
    close(tube1[0]);
    close(tube2[1]);
    close(tube2[0]);
}
```

And the output from that is:

```
fils 2 4 6 8 10 
pere 3 6 9 12 15 
fils 12 14 16 18 20 
pere 18 21 24 27 30 
fils 22 24 26 28 30 
pere 33 36 39 42 45 
fils 32 34 36 38 40 
pere 48 51 54 57 60 
fils 42 44 46 48 50 
pere 63 66 69 72 75 
fils 52 54 56 58 60 
pere 78 81 84 87 90 
fils 62 64 66 68 70 
pere 93 96 99 102 105 
fils 72 74 76 78 80
```

Note that the child doesn't reach 100 because the parent exits, and the parent overshoots 100 because the check occurs on the outer loop, not the inner loop.

I've kept your loop organization, but were it my own code, it would have two functions — `be_childish()` and `be_parental()` — which would be called after the fork and each of them would run their own relevant loop.  The pipes would be passed to the functions and they'd clean up 'better'.  Note that 2 of the 4 `close()` calls at the end of the program will fail because those pipe descriptors were closed previously.  Separating which ones is fiddly; it is better to split the code into the functions.